# Redirect Gradle's test output into file

Tags: scala, gradle

Is there a way how to tell Gradle, that I want to redirect test output into text file under 'reports' directory?

I have som Scala test sources, from which I want to capture output. I previously (in Maven) sued "scalatest-maven-plugin", with attribute "filereports" for doing this.

Thanks
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell Gradle to redirect its test console output to a file, but the generated HTML report does capture test standard out/err.

Comment: Unfortunately, Scala tests are missing in test report. I can see in console that they're executed, but "Test summary" report shows zero executed tests. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to capture at least some information about test execution by redirection to file. (test files are in standard directory src/test/scala)

Comment: Question is why they are missing, and if/how this can be fixed.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser does it still hold after 5 years? 
Can Gradle redirect test output to a file?